# const pointer to struct containing a mutex

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, mutex, const-pointer

I have something like this:

```c
typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    /* Other stuff */
} some_struct_t;

void some_func (some_struct_t *s)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&s->mtx);
    /* Some stuff */
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&s->mtx);
}
```

`some_func` does not modify `s`, and I would like to change the signature to

```c
void some_func (const some_struct_t *s);
```

but the calls to `pthreads` functions won't allow me to do that without warnings.

Is there any common idiom I could use to express that the `some_struct_t` will be *logically* constant inside the function?

Any way to use `some_func` from inside another function which has a `const some_struct_t *s` without doing a cast?

Comment: *Is there any common idiom I could use to express that the some_struct_t will be locigally constant inside the function?*  Don't redefine "logically" to reduce "locked" and "unlocked" to the same state?  Your structure isn't constant.

Comment: *some_func does not modify s*. Yes it does. By passing it to `pthread_mutex` functions.

Comment: You're modifying at least one member of `s` by invoking the pthread_mutex functions against the member mtx. It therefore cannot be const). Either separate the mutex from the structure or declare the members within the structure you want const to be explicitly so (which will probably break all sorts of other things). There is no simple fix to packing perceptually const and non-const data in the same logical object (though it is a subtle hint of a non-ideal design in hindsight).

Comment: Do you think using a cast  in `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` would be dangerous in some way?

Comment: So long as the pointer `s` refers to an *originally mutable* object, const stripping via cast is viable and has defined behavior. But seriously consider what you're doing. If you're going down that road, why declare it `const` in the first place? It protects *nothing* if you're just going to have to cast it away anyway.

Comment: Well, it is a way to force the programmer to say "I know what I am doing" while at the same time protect the parameter from superfluous/erroneous writes. For example, after adding a cast, I realized that I was extracting a `pointer` to some field in `some_struct_t` which could in fact be a `const pointer`.

Comment: I am inclined to think that most casts appearing in C code for other than arithmetic purposes say "I *don't* know what I am doing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some_func`modifies the `mtx` member, so it cannot be const.

But you can make `mtx` a pointer. You then still change the mutex, but that will no longer be covered by the const.

```
typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t *mtx;
    /* Other stuff */
} some_struct_t;

void some_func(const some_struct_t *s)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(s->mtx);
    /* Some stuff */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(s->mtx);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_t mtx = MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    some_struct s = {
        .mtx = &mtx;
    };
    some_func(&s);
}
```

Now `some_func` no longer modifies `s`, but initializing a `some_struct` variable (and cleaning it up) has become a little bit more involved.

Comment: Nice trick. It is an elegant solution without using a `cast`. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [koder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495103/11044962), you can have a redundant pointer inside `some_struct_t` to the same `mutex`, and use that instead of the address of the real `mutex`:

```c
typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t pmtx;
    pthread_mutex_t *mtx;
    /* Other stuff */
} some_struct_t;

void some_func (const some_struct_t *s)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (s->mtx);
    /* Some stuff */
    pthread_mutex_unlock (s->mtx);
}

int main ()
{
    some_struct_t  s;

    pthread_mutex_init (&s.pmtx, NULL);
    s.mtx = &s.pmtx;
    some_func (&s);
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&s.pmtx);
}
```

Alternatively, you can trick the compiler by passing the pointer to the `mutex` in another parameter, and hide that implementation detail to the programmer/user with a macro:

```c
#define some_func(a)      some_func_hidden (a, &(a)->mtx)

typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    /* Other stuff */
} some_struct_t;

void some_func_hidden (const some_struct_t *s, pthread_mutex_t *mtx)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (mtx);
    /* Some stuff */
    pthread_mutex_unlock (mtx);
}

int main ()
{
    some_struct_t  s;

    pthread_mutex_init (&s.mtx, NULL);
    some_func (&s);
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&s.mtx);
}
```

Comment: I'm not a macro expert. Anybody knows any corner case where that macro definition doesn't work as expected? (apart from the double evaluation)